# Automatic determination of zone for Apple Push Notifications

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I use Apple Push Notifications. As you know there are 2 zones: dev & prod.

So i decided to create automatic determination of zone, what zone we must use for create subscription & send push.

And embedded.mobileprovision helps me. I decided that development provision contains these lines:

```
<key>aps-environment</key>
<string>development</string>
```

and ad-hoc & distribution - these:

```
<key>aps-environment</key>
<string>production</string>
```

So i wrote this code:

```
+(BOOL)isDevelopmentProvision{

    BOOL isDev;

    NSString *profilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"embedded.mobileprovision" ofType:nil];
    NSString *profileAsString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:profilePath encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding error:NULL];
    NSRange apsenvironmentRange = [profileAsString rangeOfString:@"<key>aps-environment</key>"];

    if(apsenvironmentRange.location != NSNotFound){
        NSRange apstypeRange = [profileAsString rangeOfString:@"</" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                                                        range:NSMakeRange(apsenvironmentRange.location+apsenvironmentRange.length, 100)];

        isDev = [profileAsString rangeOfString:@"development" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(apsenvironmentRange.location+apsenvironmentRange.length, apstypeRange.location - (apsenvironmentRange.location+apsenvironmentRange.length))].location != NSNotFound;

    }

    return  isDev;
}
```

So, it works good.
But after my app was submitted to store - i see that **isDev** always TRUE and my app uses development zone for pushes.

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

May it be that the location is never found (for some reason)? You did not initialize `isDev`. As a local variable it may have unpredictable contents. `isDev` only represents `FALSE/NO` when its value is exactly zero. In all other cases it will represent `TRUE/YES`. You should change it to

```
BOOL isDev = NO;
```

Comment: BOOL isDev;  NSLog(@"isDev= %d", isDev) -> "0"  - it's OK